# Cannot convert from ArrayList<String> to List<Comparable>

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

When I write the following code compiler says that

> cannot convert from `ArrayList<String>` to `List<Comparable>`

```
private List<Comparable> get(){
    return new ArrayList<String>();
}
```

But when I write return type with wildcard, the code compiles.

```
private List<? extends Comparable> get() {
    return new ArrayList<String>();
}
```

Can somebody explain me why?

Comment: This is a great generics resource:[http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `List<String>` is not a `List<Comparable>`.
After all, you can put an `Integer` into a `List<Comparable>`.

Comment: But i can put an Integer into List<? extends Comparable>

Comment: ah, thanks) I think i got it now. Also I will try to read document posted by @binary_runner

Comment: @narek.gevorgyan: No, you cannot. In fact, you cannot put anything into a List<? extends Comparable> except null. You can only get Comparable instances from it.

Answer (score 2):

Because a `List<Comparable>` can have any instance of `Comparable` added to it, e.g. an `Integer`. An `ArrayList<String>`, however, is only allowed to contain `String` instances. Allowing it to be used as a `List<Comparable>` would break type safety.

Answer (score 1):

String is not a Comparable is it something which extends Comparable.

e.g.

```
List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
List<Comparable> list2 = list1; // does not compile.
list2.add(1); // if this program compiled you would have a 1 in the list of String.
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how the generics work. I think the best explanation is here : http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5/pdf/generics-tutorial.pdf .

Answer (score -2):

the reason is that the second part is what u actually want: a class (String) that extends Comparable. Since Comparable is an interface you cannot have an Comparable object, just a class that implements it. This is what List<? extends Comparable> tells Java to look for.

Hope it helps a little.

Alex